# Does IOT Cloud have REST APIs? Or does it uses third party platforms to connect devices to cloud?

Tags: rest-api, rest, iot

I am working on integration services for salesforce. Salesforce has APIs e.g. for creating Account, Contact, Lead etc., making it easy to develop integration services.

Now I have been asked to develop integration services for IoT-Cloud. This is where I got confused. First of all I think I need access to salesforce IOT Cloud. Is IoT cloud even for sale already? I am not sure about that yet, but assume I have access.

Does salesforce IoT cloud have REST APIs? Or does it uses third party platforms to connect devices to cloud?

As per docs, salesforce says IoT Cloud collects data from connected devices. Now if I have IoT cloud access, how will the device be connected and how will data be sent to IoT cloud? Like in SAP and Thingworx IOT, does salesforce IoT also provide APIs to create things, Connect to virtual device etc?

Answer (score 0):

I didn't get it properly. But I guess you are talking about writing integration logic inside your java code for APIs. Well salesforce have already released CRM APIs and those are well tested so easy to use. As per the sources IoT Cloud is not for sale yet. I haven't seen anything concrete yet. It's still being tested by force.com platform and not yet ready for implementation though cloud access might have been given to selected customers. Thingworx is stable and provide APIs. Salesforce recomends other platforms as a method for connecting devices to the cloud.I'd suggest you to contact your Account Executive for more information.

Answer (score 0):

In short, yes. You send a JSON payload to the endpoint the platform event used by the context (e.g. {{serverurl}}/data/v43.0/sobjects/Example__e). There are also some metadata APIs for Salesforce IoT, but these are more to help with deployment.

Salesforce IoT Explorer is now generally available as of W'18 and available in developer editions. I wrote two blog posts to help people get started and see how it fits into a larger IoT strategy:

- [Using IoT Explorer to Power Your Digital Transformation Projects](https://hub.appirio.com/tech-blog/using-iot-explorer-to-power-your-digital-transformation-projects)
- [Expanding Your IoT Explorer Prototype](https://hub.appirio.com/tech-blog/expanding-your-iot-explorer-prototype)